# Proof for error analysis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I am trying to proof the following equality for matrix error analysis. 
Sorry for all the syntax. I am new to math stack. Thanks in advance.

$$b = Ax$$

$r = A(x-\hat{x})$, where $\hat{x} =$ computed solution.

$$\frac{1}{\kappa(A)} \frac{\|r\|}{\|b\|}  \leq \frac{\|x-\hat{x}\|}{\|x\|}$$

My current work so far-

$$\frac{1}{\kappa(A)} \frac{\|r\|}{\|b\|} = \frac{1}{(\|A^{-1}\|\|A\|)} \frac{\|A(x-\hat{x})\|}{\|Ax\|}$$

$$\leq \frac{1}{(\|A^{-1}\|\|A\|)} \frac{\|A\| \|(x-\hat{x})\|}{\|A\| \|x\|}$$

$$=\frac{\|(x-\hat{x})\|}{(\|A^{-1}\|\|A\| \|x\|)}$$

I am stuck at this step and don't know how to proceed. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have a doubt how could use the $\|Ax\| \leq \|A\| \|x\|$ fact on the denominator.

Comment: You're right, thanks for pointing it out. Then I am stuck again. Is there another way I can derive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|\|A\|}=\left|\frac{\lambda_{min}(A)}{\lambda_{max}(A)}\right|\leq 1 \ [\text{applicable only for the normal matrices}]$$

$$\frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|\|A\|}=\frac{\sigma_{min}(A)}{\sigma_{max}(A)}\leq 1 \ [\text{true only when, } \|\cdot\| \text{ denotes } \|\cdot\|_2]$$
For any matrix $A, \ \kappa(A) \geq 1$.

[Please check the comments below for another approach to solve this problem.]

Comment: Thanks, the hint helps a lot.

Comment: Hi Rajada, question regarding norm division, can I directly cancel the A in ||A(x)||/||Ab|| ?

Comment: No. You can not do that.

Comment: The equality in the "hint" is not generally true (except for symmetric positive definite matrices). However, for any submultiplicative norm $\|\cdot\|$ such that $\|I\|=1$, $1=\|I\|=\|A^{-1}A\|\leq\|A^{-1}\|\|A\|$ so, in particular, this holds for any operator norm.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Thank you for your insight. I am modifying my answer based on your review.